# Showing that a transformation is a similarity

Tags: geometry

How do I show that a transformation $F$ is a similarity without having to show that it is a homomorphism? Say for example $F:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$. Is there a way of using algebra to show that for center $O$, $|OP|=r|OP'|$ where $P=(x,y)$ and $P'=F(x,y)$?

For example, suppose $F:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ where $F(x,y)=(3x,5y)$. I'm able to get that

$|OP|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|OP'|=\sqrt{4x^2+16y^2}$, but cannot go any further

Comment: Whenever I try using algebra, I'm not able to factor out a constant $r$ even when $F$ is actually a similarity.

Comment: *"Whenever I try using algebra, I'm not able to factor out a constant $r$ even when $F$ is actually a similarity."* Please provide an example of this. (Also, always add context and clarifications to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue, for example: when $F:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by $F(x,y)=(3x, 5y)$

Comment: $F(x,y)=(3x,5y)$ is not a similarity. It fixes $(0,0)$, which would then have to be the "center", but the effects on, say, $(1,0)$ vs $(0,1)$ relative to that center are not proportional.